JUnit5 listener from other library is not found
I have few different gradle projects(Proj_A, Proj_B, Proj_C etc) which contain only JUnit5 tests. I have another library package FooLibrary, in which I have defined a ResultAnalyzer to do some stuff with test results.
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestPlan;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.SummaryGeneratingListener;

@Slf4j
public class ResultAnalyzer extends SummaryGeneratingListener {
    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionFinished(TestPlan testPlan) {
        // This method is invoked after all tests in all containers is finished
        log.info("[CustomTestSummary]: Running after all tests are done.");
        super.testPlanExecutionFinished(testPlan);
        analyzeResult();
    }

    private void analyzeResult() {
        var summary = getSummary();
        var failures = summary.getFailures();
        final var testsSucceededCount = summary.getTestsSucceededCount();
        log.info("[CustomTestSummary]: Passed: {}", testsSucceededCount);
        // Do something
    }
}

I also have added the file src/test/resources/META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener in the same FooLibrary package.
Now, I want to use this FooLibrary in all test projects(Proj_A, Proj_B, Proj_C) and process their test execution results. But, so I added the dependency in all test packages and tried to run the tests, but getting following error:
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener: Provider com.apple.store.qe.utils.ResultAnalyzer not found
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1219)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:132)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.registerTestExecutionListeners(LauncherFactory.java:179)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.createDefaultLauncher(LauncherFactory.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.openSession(LauncherFactory.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.openSession(LauncherFactory.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$BackwardsCompatibleLauncherSession.open(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:318)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.createTestExecutor(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.startProcessing(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.startProcessing(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:42)
    ... 18 more

I have analyzed the contents of the .jar dependency of FooLibrary and can see that ResultAnalyzer is being bundled in the jar. If I move the ResultAnalyzer to the test packages, it works fine.
So, what changes do I need to make so that I can keep the ResultAnalyzer in FooLibrary and do not need to copy in all the test packages? Can someone please share some pointers on how can I achieve the same?

It looks like your classpath(s) are not set up correctly. Can you provide the respective maven pom or Gradle build file?


I also have added the file src/test/resources/META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener in the same FooLibrary package.

The test module is usually not provided in the jar artefact, so the test execution listener must be configured in
src/main/resources/META-INF/services.
in order to be present in the FooLibrary's jar file.
Caveat: Since the full info about Gradle build file and source code structure is not provided, my guess could be wrong.

Yes, indeed this is the solution to my problem. After moving classes an file from src/test/resources to src/main/resources, everything worked fine.
